# fault tolerant uploading tool

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-a-script, tools

I'm setting up a wordpress site for a friend who has some large audio files (around 150M). He's on a bad connection and it'll take him a while to upload those files using the normal wordpress upload tool.  I'm looking for a tool that I can install on the server that allows uploads and is also fault tolerant (for example if you loses his connection, or power, or whatever it'll pick up where it left off).  I realize normal web technologies probably don't do that, but perhaps flash or something similar will work. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be a good idea to compress all of the files into a single .zip archive, then upload that. Maybe first put it on a flash drive and bring to the local library or a friend's house to use their network connection. I understand what you're trying to do, but I've only ever heard of "resuming downloads" not uploads.

Answer (score 2):

I generally discourage uploading giant files through the browser, if possible; it just sucks. If going *around* WordPress a bit is an option, there's a plugin, [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) that allows for grabbing stuff that's already on the filesystem. So, have client ftp the files in(which gives you resuming etc. for free) and then import when ready through the WP admin.

Answer (score 0):

since the site is hosted on ec2, I'm trying out s3browser.  It's working great so far.

Comment: Was this you adding a note to your original question(in which case you should edit, not do it down here), or supplying your own answer?

Comment: I was attempting to provide an answer.  Would it be more proper to update the original questions?

Comment: No, answering your own question is fine. It just seemed like it might've been further detail to the question.